# How do I get the cell address of a table header cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1)` to pick a table header cell and I'm using `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1).Name` to get the value of that header. How would I get its address? For example, I'd like to know if the table header I'm targeting is in column `C` and row `3`.

I tried using `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1).Address` but that doesn't seem to be right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `ListColumn` has properties of `DataBodyRange` and `Range`. `Range` includes the header cell, so you can find the first cell of this range.

```
Dim col As ListColumn

Set col = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1)
MsgBox col.DataBodyRange.Address    'just the data range
MsgBox col.Range.Address            'includes the header cell

MsgBox col.Range.Cells(1).Address   'the header cell
```

Hint: Creating a reference `col` means that you can make use of intellisense to discover the members of a ListColumn object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This worked perfectly for me. I'm unfamiliar with what intellisense is and how to use it. Do you have a good resource I can use to learn?

Comment: When typing my code, after typing `col.` there is a list that pops up listing applicable methods and properties for a ListColumn. This is intellisense. You can click in a word and press F1 to access the Help system, or press F2 for the Object Browser. J Walkenbach's books VBA for Dummies or Power Programming are very good. I don't know of any online resources to recommend, other than MSDN.

Comment: One last question. Say ``col.Range.Cells(1).Address`` returns ``$E$3``. I want to know and use the fact that its column ``E``. How do I get that information?

Comment: `col.Range.Column` gives you the number 5.

Comment: If you really want the column letter "E" then you can either parse the Address-string, or add (5-1) to the character code for the letter "A", but it is not usually necessary to get the letter, unless you want to display it somewhere.